# How to print Error Message in stored procedure in SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am using SQL Server 2014. Can any one tell me that how can i print a specific Error Message in my stored procedure?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31684475/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using Throw?
SQL 2014 doesn't support RAISERROR() for native SPs. While Throw is supported.

```
  THROW [ { error_number | @local_variable },
    { message | @local_variable },
    { state | @local_variable } ] [ ; ]
```

For Example:

```
   THROW 5000, 'THROW TEST', 1
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677615.aspx

http://sqlhints.com/2013/06/30/differences-between-raiserror-and-throw-in-sql-server/