# Using Error Handling in the Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have found the below code in our stored procedure:

```
BEGIN TRAN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @rerror As Int

    if not exists(select * from OfficeSchedule 
                  where OfficeID = @officeid and WeekDate = @weekdate)
    begin

        INSERT INTO OfficeSchedule (OfficeID, WeekDate, Status, CreatedBy, CreatedDate, RowStatus)
        VALUES (@officeid, @weekdate, 'U', @createdby, GetDate(), 'A')
    end

    SET @rerror = @@error

    IF @rerror <> 0 BEGIN
       ROLLBACK TRAN
    END 
    ELSE BEGIN
        COMMIT TRAN

        SELECT @@identity
     END
```

What is the purpose of the `@error` variable. If the insert fails, does the transaction not roll back? If I modified the code by handling the else block as below:

```
  INSERT INTO OfficeSchedule (OfficeID, WeekDate, Status, CreatedBy, CreatedDate, RowStatus)
  VALUES (@officeid, @weekdate, 'U', @createdby, GetDate(), 'A')
end
Else
begin
    INSERT INTO OfficeSchedule (OfficeID, WeekDate, Status, CreatedBy, CreatedDate, RowStatus)
    VALUES (@officeid, getdate(), 'U', @createdby, GetDate(), 'A')
end
```

then is it necessary to use the error handling?

Do we get any advantages by using `error handling` in stored procedure?

Appreciate your suggestions.

Thank you

Comment: `BEGIN TRY/END TRY BEGIN CATCH/END CATCH`, your transaction in TRY block, error handling in catch block

Comment: Returns the error number for the last Transact-SQL statement executed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31684475/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Q. *What is the purpose of the `@@ERROR` variable. if the insert fails*

Returns an error number if the previous statement encountered an error. If the error was one of the errors in the `sys.messages` catalog view, then `@@ERROR` contains the value from the `sys.messages.message_id` column for that error. You can view the text associated with an `@@ERROR` error number in `sys.messages`.

Because `@@ERROR` is cleared and reset on each statement executed, check it immediately following the statement being verified, or save it to a local variable that can be checked later.
[@@ERROR Description and Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188790.aspx)

[TRANSACTION & TRY-CATCH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31684475)

Comment: Insert fails when the if not exists condition fails, but I have added the else block to handle that in the modified code. still @error required?

Comment: @bmsqldev if our `IF NOT EXISTS` is failed then query will break at same line then it will go to `CATCH` block

Comment: so, It wont execute else part then ?

Comment: @bmsqldev Yes it will not

Comment: if I want the else block to be executed, what to do?  Do I need to remove error handling and let the else part handle if insert fails?

Comment: @bmsqldev if we have to execute `ELSE` part then we can write that part in `CATCH` block but make sure this should run correctly :)

Comment: else part in catch block? can u please show an example

Comment: `BEGIN TRY
declare @tab1 table
(Id int, Name nvarchar(33), Barcode bigint)

 insert into @tab1 values(1,'item1',    NULL)
 insert into @tab1 values('xyz','Item2',    Null) -- here will fail

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
 insert into @tab1 values(2,'Item2',    Null) -- here will success
 select * from @tab1
 print 'ERROR'
END CATCH`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89153/discussion-between-bmsqldev-and-tinka).

Answer (score 0):

Use [`TRY..CATCH`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179296%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) blocks:

> A TRY…CATCH construct consists of two parts: a TRY block and a CATCH
>   block. When an error condition is detected in a Transact-SQL statement
>   that is inside a TRY block, control is passed to a CATCH block where
>   the error can be processed.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                   FROM OfficeSchedule
                   WHERE OfficeID=@officeid 
                    AND WeekDate=@weekdate)
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO OfficeSchedule (OfficeID, WeekDate, Status, CreatedBy, 
                                CreatedDate, RowStatus)
      VALUES (@officeid, @weekdate, 'U', @createdby, 
                                GetDate(), 'A');
      SELECT @@identity;
    END

    COMMIT TRAN;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRAN;
    -- log errors
END CATCH
```

For more info about error in `CATCH` block use:

> Error Functions
>
> TRY…CATCH uses the following error functions to capture error
>   information:
>
> ERROR_NUMBER() returns the error number.
>
> ERROR_MESSAGE() returns the complete text of the error message. The text includes the values supplied for any substitutable parameters
>   such as lengths, object names, or times.
>
> ERROR_SEVERITY() returns the error severity.
>
> ERROR_STATE() returns the error state number.
>
> ERROR_LINE() returns the line number inside the routine that caused the error.
>
> ERROR_PROCEDURE() returns the name of the stored procedure or trigger where the error occurred.