# How to get all error messages from SQL server procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, try-catch

In my procedure am using try catch block to catch the error details and log into a Log to table for future refference. But using `Error_message()` its getting only the last error message.

for example on executing below code,its generating two error messages

```
ALTER TABLE [MFClassProperty]

DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_MFClassProperty_MFProperty]
```

error messages are

```
Msg 3728, Level 16, State 1, Line 161
'FK_MFClassProperty_MFProperty2' is not a constraint.
Msg 3727, Level 16, State 0, Line 161
Could not drop constraint. See previous errors.
```

with my try catch block its logs only the last error message,with that message its difficult to find the issue.

Is there any way to get both error messages[in this condition].

My catch block code is adding below

```
BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

        SET NOCOUNT ON

        IF @Debug > 0
        BEGIN
            --------------------------------------------------
            -- INSERTING ERROR DETAILS INTO LOG TABLE
            --------------------------------------------------
            INSERT INTO MFLog (
                SPName
                ,ErrorNumber
                ,ErrorMessage
                ,ErrorProcedure
                ,ErrorState
                ,ErrorSeverity
                ,ErrorLine
                ,ProcedureStep
                )
            VALUES (
                'spName'
                ,Error_number()
                ,Error_message()
                ,Error_procedure()
                ,Error_state()
                ,Error_severity()
                ,Error_line()
                ,@ProcessStep
                )
        END             
    END CATCH
```

Comment: i hope this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31684475

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: Am using SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is a limitation of SQL Server that it will only return the last error message.

Technically you are receiving two errors:

- **3728** 'FK_MFClassProperty_MFProperty2' is not a constraint.
- **3727** Could not drop constraint. See previous errors.

SQL Server is therefore returning the last one. i.e. **3727**.

Take a look at the following thread:

[SQL Server try-catch inner exception message conundrum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3476a931-3db7-4017-9fbe-e082f2de2cb0/sql-server-trycatch-inner-exception-message-conundrum?forum=transactsql)